# How to implement an F# interface with a member returing an instance of that interface?

Tags: interface, f#, interface-implementation

Let's say I have the following interface in F#:

```
type InterfaceA =
 abstract Magic : InterfaceA -> InterfaceA
```

How can I implement such interface?
When I try to do it like this:

```
type MyTypeA = {x:int} with
 interface InterfaceA with
  member self.Magic another = 
   {x=self.x+another.x}
```

I get the error:
`This expression was expected to have type    'InterfaceA'    but here has type    'MyTypeA'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix the type error, you need to explicitly cast the returned value to the `InterfaceA` type - unlike for example C#, F# does not do this automatically:

```
type InterfaceA =
 abstract Magic : InterfaceA -> InterfaceA
 abstract Value : int

type MyTypeA = 
  {x:int} 
  interface InterfaceA with
    member self.Value = self.x
    member self.Magic another = 
      { x=self.x+another.Value } :> InterfaceA
```

Note that your code also did not work because `another` was of type `InterfaceA` and so it did not have the `x` field you could access. To fix this, I added a member `Value` to the interface.

Comment: Just a note that you can omit the interface name in the cast to make it a bit shorter: `{ x=self.x+another.Value } :> _`. The compiler will infer the correct type. Also, this cast isn't needed at all in F# 6.

Answer (score 3):

Posting as an alternative that's not really better, just different:

As of F# 6, you can also annotate the return type and the compiler will infer what you mean:

```
type InterfaceA =
 abstract Magic : InterfaceA -> InterfaceA
 abstract Value : int

type MyTypeA = 
  {x:int} 
  interface InterfaceA with
    member self.Value = self.x
    member self.Magic another : InterfaceA = 
      { x=self.x+another.Value }
```